# Запретить нажимать на кнопку, если input равен 1 JS

Tags: javascript

Как запретить нажимать на кнопку, если input имеет значение value = 1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
 <input type="text" id ="inputId" oninput="checkValue()" name="input" value="1">
 <button id="buttonId">Check</button>
 <script>
   function checkValue() {
     let input = document.getElementById('inputId')
     let button = document.getElementById('buttonId')
     if (input.value === '1')
       button.disabled = true
     else 
       button.disabled = false
   }
   window.onload = checkValue()
 </script>
```

Comment: а как сделать, чтобы кнопка сразу отключалась, если в input уже есть цифра 1, а не в том случае, когда её нужно ввести ?

Comment: вместо html тега input ставь это <input type="text" id ="inputId" oninput="checkValue()" name="input" value="1" placeholder = "Enter anything">

Answer (score 3):

1. Повесить обработчик на событие onInput для инпута
2. В нем получать значение инпута и сравнивать его с 1
3. Если true - кнопке ставишь свойство disabled, иначе убираешь

Answer (score 1):

Просто пример без oninput

```js
const input = document.querySelector('#inputId');
const button = document.querySelector('#buttonId')

function checkValue() {
  button.disabled = input.value === '1';
}

checkValue();
input.addEventListener('input', checkValue);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inputId" name="input" value="1">
<button id="buttonId">Check</button>
```